# Element value set by modal button action is not working in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

My code for jquery is: (this will trigger on modal button click)

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-modal-remove-button', function () {
    $('#code-output').attr('da-url',"1111");
});
```

My code for html is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="problemCode" id="code-output" da-url=2/>
```

problem is that there is a button in my page, on this button click modal opens and in the modal there is also a button contains class
`js-modal-remove-button` 
on the action of that i need to set the my main page(on which where modal opening button present) da-url value

Comment: Is the action click on .js-modal-etc working? do a console.log for get sure is calling it.

Comment: yes it's working

Comment: and you are NOT repeating id#code-output more than once right?... maybe if you create a new class for binding.. like $(document).on('click', '.sendDaUrl', function () { ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just and another class to your button and use this jquery
**HTML**

```
<button class="js-modal-remove-button model_button_class"></button>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-modal-remove-button .model_button_class', function () {
    $('#code-output').attr('da-url',"1111");
});
```

Here `.model_button_class` is the another class .
I thing it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.js-modal-remove-button .model_button_class').on('click',function(){
    $('#code-output').attr('da-url',"1111");  });
```